# Adding Items to my ArrayList doesn't update the ListView correctly

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview, arraylist

I have a ListView that I am trying to update from a database after adding to the database.

While the data is into the List, and also getting into the ListView, the ListView isn't updating the number of items in the List.

So if my list was {1, 3, 6, 8, 12}
After adding 4 to the List and sorting, my list view shows {1, 3, 4, 6 ,8}
not showing the 6th item 12.

This problem compounds itself as I add more to the list, where if I were to add another item, this ListView would still only show the first 5.

Here is the code area having problems

```
TourGroup group = data.getParcelableExtra(TOURGROUP);

DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
db.addGroup(group);

mainList = db.getAllGroups();

db.close();

Collections.sort(mainList, new CustomComparator());

ListView groupList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.groupList);
ArrayAdapter adapter = (ArrayAdapter) groupList.getAdapter();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

If I replace

```
mainList = db.getAllGroups();
```

With

```
mainList.add(group);
```

then the ListView updates correctly. But this is not the solution I want, as this wouldn't be updating the List view from the database.

I've been banging my head on this problem for hours now, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the data type returned by db.getAllGroups()

Comment: If the problem is at mainList = db.getAllGroups(), then you'll have to show us the implementation of getAllGroups(). For all we know, it could be doing a ton of bad things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But this is not the solution I want, as this wouldn't be updating the List view from the database.

Your `ArrayAdapter` is wrapping around some `ArrayList`. Whatever that `ArrayList` is, it is not the `ArrayList` returned by `getAllGroups()`. There, I am willing to bet that you just created a new `ArrayList`. If so, your `ArrayAdapter` does not know about any of the changes you made to the database, because it's a different `ArrayList`.

Either:

- Update your existing `ArrayList`, or
- Use `add()`, `addAll()`, `clear(),`insert()`,`remove()`, and/or`sort()`on your`ArrayAdapter`(which also saves you the trouble of calling`notifyDataSetChanged()`, or
- Create a new `ArrayAdapter` for your new `ArrayList` and attach the new `ArrayAdapter` to your `ListView`

Comment: Thank you
I got it to work with
`mainList.clear();`
`mainList.addAll(db.getAllGroups());`
I hope this is an appropriate way to do it.

Comment: @bleem313: That should be OK.